# Finding the probability density function...

Tags: probability, statistics

I've found the probability density function for other functions, but this one seems rather difficult.

$$F(x)=P(X\le x)=1-e^{-x^2}$$

My teacher's solution manual is showing:

$$
\begin{cases} 0, & x<0 \\ 2xe^{-x}, &  x>0 \end{cases}
$$

Maybe I am just having a hard time finding this integral, but I don't seem to get the same results. If I use u-substitution I am setting $u = x^2$ where $du = 2x$ then, but how does that get into the answer, am I selecting a wrong $u$? Is it integration by parts maybe?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a typo? I think the PDF for $x > 0$ should be $2x e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: You should have $du = 2x\,dx,$ not $du = 2x. \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the density function is given by
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x<0$,} \\[2ex]
2xe^{-x^2}, & \text{if $x\ge0$,}
\end{cases}
$$ then we have, by the change of variable, $u=t^2$, $du=2tdt$,
$$
F(x)=\int_0^x2t e^{-t^2}dt=\int_0^{x^2}e^{-u}du=\left[-e^{-u}\right]_0^{x^2}=1-e^{-x^2}
$$ as announced.

Answer (score 0):

If $F_{\small X}(x) = (1-\mathsf e^{-x^2})~\mathbf 1_{x>0}$

Then $f_{\small X}(x) = \dfrac{\mathrm d~~~}{\mathrm d~x}F_{\small X}(x)\\ \qquad = -\dfrac{\mathrm d~\mathsf e^{-x^2} }{\mathrm d ~x\quad}~\mathbf 1_{x>0}\\\qquad = \left.-\dfrac{\mathrm d~(-x^2)}{\mathrm d~x\qquad}\dfrac{\mathrm d~\mathsf e^{u}}{\mathrm d~u~}\right\rvert_{u=(-x^2)} ~\mathbf 1_{x>0}\\\qquad = 2x\mathsf e^u\big\rvert_{u=(-x^2)} ~\mathbf 1_{x>0}\\\qquad = 2x\mathsf e^{-x^2}~\mathbf 1_{x>0}$